# Game development on android using tools like Construct 2

Tags: android, construct-2

I tried out the Construct 2 for developing a small game yesterday and I pretty liked it. I was curious on using it for game development in Android. It did give an option to export my project to Android but of course I had the trial edition and had to purchase the product for that.

I wanted to know if there are any open source products which are like Construct 2 and can be used for Game development in Android.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search brought up the following open source frameworks for game development:
http://www.emo-framework.com/

http://unity3d.com/ (They have a lighter free version)

There are more, but I do not have enough reputation to post that many links. I would personally recommend unity, its a framework that I work a lot with.